# transaction.atomic() inside celery task

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

The code below is rising InternalError('SAVEPOINT can only be used in transaction blocks\n',) sometimes. I know that inside transaction.atomic we cannot call celery task, but cannot find whether it's ok to use atomic request inside celery task (I need atomicity in celery task).

```
@celery.task(default_retry_delay=2 * 60, max_retries=2)  # retry in 2 minutes
def update_matching(company_id=None, shop_id=None):
    """
    creates active matchings between shops & companies
    """
    from customers.models import Shop, Matching
    from sellers.models import SellRegion, Company
    from products.models import Item
    from utils.procedures import update_items_timestamp_query
    logger.info(u"company_id: %s shop_id: %s" % (company_id, shop_id))
    company = Company.objects.filter(id=company_id).first()
    shop = Shop.objects.filter(id=shop_id).first()
    try:
        shops = [shop] if shop else Shop.objects.all()
        sell_regions = SellRegion.objects.filter(company=company, is_active=True).select_related("district") if company else SellRegion.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        for shop in shops:
            # here was transaction.atomic()
            logger.info(u"shop: %s " % shop)
            Matching.objects.filter(shop=shop, company__in=[x.company for x in sell_regions]).update(is_active=False)
            shop_category_ids = [x.category.id for x in shop.categories.filter(active=True)]
            for sell_region in sell_regions.filter(district=shop.district).select_related("company"):
                # check district & if category is active in this district
                if getattr(sell_region, SellRegion.get_category_name(shop.category)):
                # check whether categories match
                    if sell_region.company.categories.filter(category__id__in=shop_category_ids, active=True).exists():
                        logger.info(u"shop: %s company: %s" % (shop, sell_region.company))
                        Matching.objects.register(shop=shop, company=sell_region.company)
                        update_items_timestamp_query(sell_region.company.id)
    except Exception, exc:
        logger.error(exc)
        raise update_matching.retry(exc=exc)
```

This is the full query:
    the problem was already solved, but as u see, the queries are not optimized and this celery task is called very often. There is also postgres stored function called(update_items_timestamp_query).

Comment: why do you need  celery task for a database query execution?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I need to update something in celery task, there are several update queries, hence I want to rollback if something happened in any of these queries

Comment: Use a atomic and inside this use a try catch block. It's really not a good idea to use celery for such simple task

Comment: @ArpitSolanki It's not a simple task, I just simplified in order to make it more clear. These queries to DB must be async (doesn't matter why).

Comment: Databases can do queries very fast and believe me if you put up to 10K queries it won't be too much for dB and it can be done using atomic transactions no need of celery.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I edited and added the full query. The question was not why not to use simple queries in code without celery task, I wanted just to know why that error raises. As you see, the query is complex (I know how to optimize it, I dont need it) and takes time some time.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this @AibekPrenov? I have the same issue, and you're right, it doesn't matter why you're doing it, I also have a perfectly good reason for needing celery tasks, and to do things atomicly within.